# How do I list Javascript array of objects in HTML

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const people = [
    { name: 'Bill', dob: '1949-08-11' },
    { name: 'Jill', dob: '1949-08-18' }
]
```

I'd like to list them inside my html document, inside a wrapper div.

This is what I tried.
I'm using a for loop like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    wrapper.innerHTML = people[i].name   
}
```

But this only outputs one name.

The same happens when I try it with `forEach`

```
people.forEach( person => {
    console.log(person.name)
   wrapper.innerHTML = person.name
})
```

The console.log lists both names, but in the html only one item is listed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are overwriting the HTML each time. Alternatively, see [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variable to store it

```
var content = "";
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    content += people[i].name + " ";   
}
wrapper.innerHTML = content;
```

Another choice is to create element dynamiclly

```js
const people = [
    { name: 'Bill', dob: '1949-08-11' },
    { name: 'Jill', dob: '1949-08-18' }
];

var ul = document.querySelector("#user_list");
people.forEach(p =>{
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = "name: " +p.name +"    dob: " + p.dob;
  ul.append(li);
});
```

```html
<div>
  User infos:
  <ul id="user_list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the content of innerHTML on every call.
you need to append the contents, something like

```
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
 wrapper.innerHTML =  wrapper.innerHTML +"<br>";
    wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML + people[i].name  ; 
}
```

this should work.